# Ldap Timestamp converting issue

Tags: php, ldap

Here is the code I am following to convert ldap timestamp into some date format. here: `https://ideone.com/Kfgd32`

I am comparing my output with this: `http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php`

My output is showing different from actual ouput showned in above link.

**Update:**
I even followed below code but still showing me wrong minutes, here:

```
https://ideone.com/4gcj3f
```

Compare output with this:  `http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php`

Comment: Please show your input, your actual output and expected output

Comment: @michaldo you can find input , output here: https://ideone.com/UTjcJl  Anyway, input is: '20150709142652Z' , output: 16 May, 2009 09:05:51 AM IST

Comment: Your post became unreadable. There are too many links, not clear which is actual and which is deprecated. Please update you post: 1 URL for ideone, show input, show actual output, 1 URL for epochconverter, show expected output and describe what is wrong (whole date or only minute)

Comment: @michaldo there are actually 3 links only.

Code1 --> https://ideone.com/Kfgd32  

Code2 --> https://ideone.com/4gcj3f
 
for checking the real output --> http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php

Comment: https://ideone.com/4gcj3f   showing wrong minutes

Answer (score 1):

Wrong date formatting: `m` stands for month, not minute.

> m     Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php